Fighter planes join up to form a robot
I don't remember the entire plot. But there was this TV animation series (could be anime), in which there are 3 fighter planes which combine to become a massive robot. This robot then goes on to fight monsters (could be aliens).
Each plane becomes a specific part of the robot, Plane #1 its head, Plane #2 arms and chest region and Plane #3 becomes the feet.
I had seen this in early 90s (in India) and I believe it could be American or Japanese because in one of the episodes the robot strikes the bombs thrown at it using a lamppost (kind of similar to Baseball).
Can anybody identify this animation TV series.

GoForce? or aka: Battle of the Planets?Check this out and see if it what you are remembering.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07P5f6TY9RQ

This is correct. Can you post it as a answer?

I have been looking for this same cartoon for a while. There were 3 airplanes, and they combined into one to make a robot. But the robot changed depending on the order that they combined.....so there were 3 larger robots depending on the combination. Each episode was about one of the larger robots, so in the opening credits....you saw the combination and knew "Oh, this is an episode about...." Cant figure out what it was. Probably Japanese, and around late 70's or early 80's.

I think you are talking about Getter Robo




GForce? or aka: Battle of the Planets?Check this out and see if it what you are remembering.




There is a show which seems to match your search criteria. You're referring to both animation and live action-Super Human Samurai Cyber Squad. One of the Lawrence brothers(Mrs. Doubtfire) was in it. They could take control of vehicles in cyber space.
