# 70s or 80s anime movie with robot mammoth

Tags: identify-this-movie, anime

I remember watching an anime movie in the 80s that had one particular scene towards the end where the main characters had to face a giant robotic mammoth. There was lots of snow and ice around, and somehow the characters were able to cut off the mammoth's tusks one by one which disabled it. I believe there was a scene that showed people controlling the elephant from the head (behind the eyes), or maybe it was the good guys after bringing down the machine.

I'm pretty sure it was from Japan, but dubbed in English. I think the overall plot was that the main characters (who were human) were adventuring around the world.

I've been trying to remember the name for a long time. I recently found out the name of another movie I watched numerous times as a kid (Rise of the Dinosaurs), so this one is next on my list! Thanks for any help!

Comment: Gaiking had some dinosaur based robot vehicles, https://dailypop.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/gaiking5.jpg?w=690 could the Mammoth have been a villain?

Comment: Could it be the same show as this? http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33795/fighter-planes-join-up-to-form-a-robot/33925#33925

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmNs5DuXDdg

Comment: @Drai No, the mammoth was only a machine, not really a villain but only a tool of the villains.

Comment: @Davesexcel I don't think so because I remember it being a movie not a series. I watched both those clips and they don't look familiar. 

From my memory, the protagonists were on a quest for something, and the giant mammoth appeared during a dark and ominous snowstorm. It was this colossal machine that tried to stomp on the characters.

Comment: [Choujuu Kishin Dancougar](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2255/Choujuu_Kishin_Dancougar) is the only '80s mammoth mecha anime i could find. Do you remember what the characters looked like and which channel/time it was on?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman No, I'm pretty sure it was a movie though. I guess my memory is not good enough to solve this

Answer (score 3):

[Zoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoids) include [2 elephants and a mammoth](http://zoids.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Zoids), all sentient robotic vehicles.

There are four anime series and at least [one unofficial and recent movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoSbFbcShIM), which isn't mentioned in the Wiki.

The big elephant, Elephander, is from 2000 so can't be it:

[image: Elephander]

[Mammoth](http://zoids.wikia.com/wiki/Mammoth) is part of the 1983 line:

[image: Mammoth]

Comment: That doesn't look like it: the elephant didn't look so toy-like. Right, it had to be made from 1980s or earlier.